# v-on:click with target not in the correct element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to do something to the anchor tag (with jQuery), like change it's color when clicked but I can't seem to get the right target.

```
<a v-on:click="action($event)">
    <span>entry 1</span>
    <span>entry 2</span>
</a>
```

The **event.target** in action is either the first or second span, never the a tag.

For example

```
$( $event.target ).css( "backgroundColor", "red" )
```

Every time I click on "a" tag - one of the spans will turn red but not the actual "a" tag that has the v-on:click directive. Is there a way to target the actual element where the click directive is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using jQuery in combination with vuejs? If you use the power of vuejs, you can do something like this:

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a v-on:click="aClicked = true" :class="{ 'clicked': aClicked }">
    <span>entry 1</span>
    <span>entry 2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Because I wanted to run another function when I click the element that does something else

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The answer of @Jns is the correct answer for your question. Please mark that one as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$event.target` you have to use `$event.currentTarget`. Then you assign your style to the `a`-tag.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
   action: function($event){
     $($event.currentTarget).css( "backgroundColor", "red" )
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a v-on:click="action($event)">
    <span>entry 1</span>
    <span>entry 2</span>
  </a>
</div>
```