# How to get the Element which has the Click Event, not e.target element since e.target can be any child element of the clicked element? Vue 3 JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to get the element on which the click event is attached. But whenever I click and try to access event.target it only returns the exact clicked element. So, when I click on a child element, I get only the child element. not it's parent which has the click event. In normal javascript I could send the target with `this` keyword. But it seems Vue Js has no way of doing this.

So, What I need is the Vue Js code of the pure javascript code below:

```js
function clicked(element){
  console.log(element.getElementsByTagName("ul"));
}
```

```html
<li onclick="clicked(this)">
  <a href="#" class="d-block p-3 text-white outline-none w-100 h-100">
    <i class="icon-envelope"></i> Messages
  </a>
  <ul>
    .....
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want something like below:

```js
methods: clicked(element){
  console.log(element.getElementsByTagName("ul"));
}
```

```html
<li @click="clicked(this)">
  <a href="#" class="d-block p-3 text-white outline-none w-100 h-100">
    <i class="icon-envelope"></i> Messages
  </a>
  <ul>
    .....
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: did you try using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`? Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708130/5334486 - MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that. Finally solved the issue

Comment: Glad it worked, I'm going to flag this question as a duplicate of the one linked above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [v-on:click with target not in the correct element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707399/v-onclick-with-target-not-in-the-correct-element)

Comment: Yes. It was exactly what I was searching for

Comment: Try `@click.self`. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

Comment: Hi @Phil. Hmm I have seen that later. Thanks though